# Build ANT Project which includes another project

Tags: java, ant, build

I have 2 Projects:

1. Project1 - Independent
2. Project2 - Includes Project1 in the "Projects" tab under "Build Path" (Eclipse Junu)

**My Ant build.xml (project2) looks like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project basedir="." default="all" name="Project2">
<property name="projectName" value="Project2"/>
<property environment="env"/>
<property name="runnerRoot" value="${env.RUNNER_ROOT}"/>
<property name="dist" value="../FluidFsAuto/lib"/>
<property name="buildFilesDir" value="${runnerRoot}/dev"/>
<import file="${buildFilesDir}/buildHelper.xml"/>
</project>
```

I am getting undefined errors such as: 
"cannot find symbol" ... etc...

How, can i use ANT build to compile project2 with the build.xml?

Comment: paste you complete error message , that will help others to easily and quickly answer

Comment: There are a lot of errors but they all look alike:
    [javac] M:\main.qa_FluidFsAuto-idans\qa\qa_FluidFsAuto\Storage\src\com\fluidfs\infra\stations\storage\StorageContainer.java:6: package com.fluidfs.infra.cli does not exist
    [javac] import com.fluidfs.infra.cli.Storage;

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html) task to run tasks from other build file.

But at this point you should consider using [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/).

--- Edit ---

Here is some example of how to call multiple build.xml files in sequence:

```
<target name="myTask1">
    <!-- simple call to the build.xml -->
    <ant antfile="../project2/build.xml" target="myTask2"/>

    <!-- to pass a property to the target build.xml, use this -->
    <ant antfile="../project3/build.xml" target="myTask3">
        <property name="myProperty1" value="myValue1"/>
    </ant>

    <!-- to pass all properties to the target build.xml, use inheritAll -->
    <property name="myProperty2" value="myValue2"/>
    <ant antfile="../project4/build.xml" target="myTask4" inheritAll="true"/>
</target>
```

More examples [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html).

Comment: The project2 compiles just fine, so why ANT build can't understand which project is included in this case ?

Comment: I'd go with `<ant antfile="project1/build.xml" />` from the project2 build file, without imports.

Comment: can i just make a single ant file that would call to:
project1/build.xml --> project3/build.xml --> project2/build.xml ; In a sequential order ? does anyone have an example of this ?

Comment: @Idan Edited my answer with an example.